# Installing Java 14 on Azure pipeline for MacOS agent

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I need to use Java 14 on a hosted agent (macos-12) and I'm trying to install it through a script and then use the JavaToolInstaller task to make it available.

I have modified the script from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer?view=azure-devops

```
jobs:
- job: RunApiTests
  pool:
    vmImage: macOS-12
  condition: ne(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')
  steps:
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    displayName: Install Java 14
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '14'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      jdkSourceOption: AzureStorage
      azureResourceManagerEndpoint: {azureResourceManagerEndpoint}
      azureStorageAccountName: {azureStorageAccountName}
      azureContainerName: openjdk
      azureCommonVirtualFile: 'openjdk-14.0.2.zip'
      jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(agent.toolsDirectory)/jdk14'
      cleanDestinationDirectory: false
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
##[error]JDK file is not valid. Verify if JDK file contains only one root folder with 'bin' inside.
```

I downloaded the `14.0.2 (build 14.0.2+12) jdk` for Mac from https://jdk.java.net/archive/ and I compressed only the `Home` folder to a zip file because `bin` is in there.

So, as per the requirement, the zip file contains only one root folder `'Home'` with `bin` inside.

I need help on why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to test your yaml in my pipeline and it works. The following are my steps.

I downloaded this package:

[image]

In my zip, I have these files:

[image]

Uploaded to the storage account.

[image]

Yaml:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: macos-12

steps:
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'AzureStorage'
    azureResourceManagerEndpoint: 'myEndpoint'
    azureStorageAccountName: 'teststorage'
    azureContainerName: 'test'
    azureCommonVirtualFile: 'homefolder.zip'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(agent.toolsDirectory)/jdk14'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: false
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you left the "azureResourceManagerEndpoint" property empty?

Comment: Just to hide the name of my subscription as it contains my subscription  ID in it. It is not empty. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Was able to fix the issue. I had to select and zip the sub-directions (bin, conf, include etc.). I was zipping the directory which contained the sub-directories before.